# Laravel Sorting data from db with where clause

Tags: php, laravel

So i have this in my controller

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::where('reviewed', '=' , 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    $url = asset('img/logo.gif');
    $mytime = Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $this->layout->content = View::make('partials.index', array('posts' => $posts->paginate(9)))->with('img', $url)->with('date' , $mytime);
}
```

What i want to happen is i want to sort out my post by created_at time stamp but i dont know how to do this properly and this line in $post var ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC') doesn't seem to work.

so how can i do this properly?

Comment: have you seen the return of the posts variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
 $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->where('reviewed', '=' , 1)->get();
```

Comment: i have add my answer please check it and let me know

Comment: actually my code was working but anyway thanks for helping :) appreciate it much thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to chain the `get()` method, as stated by Deena.

```
$posts = Post::where('reviewed', '=' , 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()
```

Could you please dump your `$posts` variable and show the result ?